# bootstrap 5 images are on their own lines despite being able to fit in column

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have several images that are 50x50, fit into a row of 6 columns (ie, 6 images to a row). However, on rendering each image is seemingly on its own individual row, so it looks like the images are stacked on top of another, instead of on a single row.

The code is simple:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See live example: https://jsfiddle.net/sedf765k/

The problem is confusing because there are 6 `col-xs-2` which add up to `12`, so they should perfectly be aligned in the row. Why is this happening, and how can I properly line them up in the row?

**Additionally**, because the images are smaller than the row itself in most cases, is there a way to decrease the empty space between them and float them to the left nicely, so that it looks like each image is next to each other, like people standing in a line?

Comment: Can you add images showing how currently it looks and another image showing how the result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because bootstrap 5 doesn't have '`xs`' breakpoint,
just use `col-2` instead of `col-xs-2` and it will work as desired

bootstrap 5 breakpoints: `sm, md, lg, xl, xxl`

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img style="height:50px;width:50px" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ah kk, that's my bad. I read the documentation and kept thinking `xs` was valid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/

Is there a way to float them to the left nicely, removing all that empty space?

Comment: add 'g-0' on row like  <div class="row g-0"> and 'img-fluid' to img like <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.seiu1000.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg" />

Answer (score 0):

when I try the link you gave
I don't think the bootstrap is used,
maybe because the link you entered is wrong
try entering the css and js links in the html correctly

check documentation

css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi i don't quite understand. Do you see the images stacked vertically in the fiddle? It shouldn't be that way.

Comment: it happened because bootstrap framework was not called properly @doejoe

Comment: check documentation, or try input the link css to html in console it will work @doejoe

Comment: added correct link, the problem still persists

Comment: and change the col-xs to col @doejoe